# Pass type as parameter to LINQ Field method

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, ado.net, linq-to-dataset

Below we have a list for a mock database call and a little program that takes that list and converts it do a DataTable.  In this example I'm using a variable for the column name to access that column's values and get the average.  However, I made a call to the `Field` method and gave it the type of int.  It doesn't appear to be possible to pass a variable to the generic `Field` method.  Is there another way to access a DataTable's column values and return something like an average without knowing the type of the column until runtime?

```
 public class Icd
{
    public int ConditionCode { get; set; }
    public string ConditionName { get; set; }

    public static List<Icd> GetIcdList()
    {
        return new List<Icd>()
        {
            new Icd() { ConditionCode = 111, ConditionName = "Condition 1" },
            new Icd() { ConditionCode = 222, ConditionName = "Condition 2" },
        };
    }
}
var icdList = Icd.GetIcdList();
var columnName = "ConditionCode";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt =  icdList.ToList().ListToDataTable();
var avg = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x[columnName] != DBNull.Value)
                            //possible to pass a variable to the field method?
                           .Average(x => x.Field<int>(columnName));
Console.WriteLine(avg); //<-- correct answer
```

**Update:** I tried to add:

```
Type t = typeof(int)
```

and do

```
x => x.Field<t>(columnName)
```

but that gives me the error:

> The type or namespace 't' could not be found

ListToDataTable helper method:

```
public static DataTable ListToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
    for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
        dt.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
    }
    object[] values = new object[props.Count];
    foreach (T t in data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = props[i].GetValue(t);
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(values);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error ? Please share it with us.

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might be helpful to you.

Comment: @abatishchev antiquated machine at work is .NET 4.0 :(

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: No worries! The extension method exists since .NET 3.5 (just reference `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`)

Answer (score 2):

I think you may use the `dynamic` type here.

For example:

```
var avg = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x[columnName] != DBNull.Value)
                            //possible to pass a variable to the field method?
                           .Average(x => x.Field<dynamic>(columnName));
```

I have done minimal testing, and it seems to work. Others are welcome to comment on this.

Cheers

Comment: I thought the same thing :) I'm going to write a `TryGetAverage` method that will call `GetAverage` if the try method is a float, double, int, etc. type.

Answer (score 1):

Generic types must be known at compile time. If you want to make that variable you need to use reflection:

```
// Get the method information
MethodInfo method = typeof(T).GetMethod("Field");

// here hardcoded for int, but you could use any type
var types = new Type[] {typeof(int)};

// Create a generic instance of that method
MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(types);

var avg = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x[columnName] != DBNull.Value)
                        // Use the generic method with target x and parameter columnName
                       .Average(x => genericMethod.Invoke(x, columnName);
```

Comment: Not sure how much reflection would actually slow things down, but what I think I'm going to do is cast the column type at dynamic and use a `TryGetAverage` that will execute if all of the values are ints, doubles, floats, etc.